# Problem with conan package manager while inspect and build

Tags: c++, linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, conan

Below conan cmd failed with invalid syntax, but that file is not created by me.
Not sure why below error is appearing.

```
$ conan inspect poco/1.9.4
poco/1.9.4: Not found in local cache, looking in remotes...
poco/1.9.4: Trying with 'conancenter'...
Downloading conanmanifest.txt completed [0.74k]
Downloading conanfile.py completed [14.36k]
Downloading conan_export.tgz completed [0.30k]
Decompressing conan_export.tgz completed [0.00k]
poco/1.9.4: Downloaded recipe revision 0
ERROR: Error loading conanfile at '/home/snandi/.conan/data/poco/1.9.4/_/_/export/conanfile.py': Unable to load conanfile in /home/snandi/.conan/data/poco/1.9.4/_/_/export/conanfile.py
  File "/home/snandi/.conan/data/poco/1.9.4/_/_/export/conanfile.py", line 97
    tools.get(**self.conan_data["sources"][self.version],
                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: do you have the latest version of conan and are you using python 3?

Comment: Yes i have latest version of conan(1.40). I have basically both python2 and python3. When i installed conan and pip at that time python 2 was present later i installed python3. Can you please suggest how do i resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error occurs because Python 2 can not parse `**self.conan_data` due unpack feature improvement introduced on Python 3.5 ([PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/)), you have to use Python 3 only.

You can validate it simply running:

```
$ python2
Python 2.7.18 (default, Mar 24 2021, 14:28:23) 
[GCC 10.2.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> dict(**{'x': 1}, y=2, **{'z': 3})
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    dict(**{'x': 1}, y=2, **{'z': 3})
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

```
$ python3
Python 3.9.6 (default, Jun 30 2021, 10:22:16) 
[GCC 11.1.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> dict(**{'x': 1}, y=2, **{'z': 3})
{'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
```

Thus, to solve your problem:

First, uninstall Conan from python2: `python2 -m pip uninstall conan`

Then, keep only the python 3 version installed: `python3 -m pip install -U conan`

If you have some difficult managing your Python environment in your host, I would suggest using [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv), which manage the global version installed.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I will try this out and update here.